# Twilio receive user input during a conference call

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, voice, conference

Let us say,if there are 3 participants in conference room.
Is it possible to receive user input using gather options during a conference call in twilio using node js without ending the call or transferring the call.

Answer (score 0):

A conference call cannot also receive input via `<Gather>`. The only thing you can do in a conference call is set [`hangupOnStar` on the `<Dial>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar) and when a caller uses it, direct them to a `<Gather>` afterwards to make their selection, then direct them back into the conference.